# GCP Airflow Operators: BQ LOAD and sensor for job ID

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, airflow

I need to schedule automatically a `bq load` process that gets AVRO files from a GCS bucket and load them in BigQuery, and wait for its completion in order to execute another task upon completion, specifically a task that will read from above mentioned table.
As showed here there is a nice API to run this [command][1] , example given:

```
 bq load \
    --source_format=AVRO \
    mydataset.mytable \
    gs://mybucket/mydata.avro
```

This will give me a job_id

```
Waiting on bqjob_Rsdadsajobc9sda5dsa17_0sdasda931b47_1 ... (0s) Current status
```

job_id that I can check with `bq show --job=true bqjob_Rsdadsajobc9sda5dsa17_0sdasda931b47_1`

And that is nice... I guess under the hood the `bq load` job is a DataTransfer. I found some operators related to this: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/operators/cloud/bigquery_dts.html

Even if the documentation does not cover specifically avro load configuration, digging through the documentation, gave me what I was looking for.

My question is: Is there an easier way of getting the status of the job given a job_id similar to the `bq show --job=true <job_id>` command?

Is there something that might help me in not going through creating a DataTransferJob, starting it, monitoring it and then delete it (because, I don't need it to stay there since next time the parameters will change).

Maybe a custom sensor, using the python-sdk-api?

Thank you in advance.
[1]: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-avro

Comment: Hi, have you also considered using the BigQueryInsertJobOperator (https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/_api/airflow/providers/google/cloud/operators/bigquery/index.html#airflow.providers.google.cloud.operators.bigquery.BigQueryInsertJobOperator). With it you can create a load job and it should return to you the Job ID on completion.

Comment: @p13rr0m Hi, I did see it, but could not find any prebuilt sensor from gcp_bigquery. Mmmm that because `Executes a BigQuery job. Waits for the job to complete and returns job id.` But that might be enough, to be honest!

Comment: I don't completely understood your need. You want executing a task after finishing to load the Avro file to BigQuery ?

Comment: @MazlumTosun yes, indeed

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use [GCSToBigQueryOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/_api/airflow/providers/google/cloud/transfers/gcs_to_bigquery/index.html) operators and tasks sequencing with `Airflow` to solve your issue :

```py
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.transfers.gcs_to_bigquery import GCSToBigQueryOperator

with airflow.DAG(
        'dag_name',
        default_args=your_args,
        schedule_interval=None) as dag:

    load_avro_to_bq = GCSToBigQueryOperator(
        task_id='load_avro_file_to_bq',
        bucket={your_bucket},
        source_objects=['folder/{SOURCE}/*.avro'],
        destination_project_dataset_table='{your_project}:{your_dataset}.{your_table}',
        source_format='AVRO',
        compression=None,
        create_disposition='CREATE_NEVER',
        write_disposition='WRITE_TRUNCATE'
    )

    second_task = DummyOperator(task_id='Next operator', dag=dag)
    
    load_avro_to_bq >> second_task
```

- The first operator allows to load the `Avro` file from `GCS` to `BigQuery`
- If this operator is in success, the second task is executed otherwise it's not executed

Comment: Hi, I tried and I realized that is basically an extension of BigQueryInsertJobOperator. This is useful because it simplifies some parameters, but risking of miss out on some feature (namely `useAvroLogicalTypes`). So I think it gives more space to manouvre using the `BigQueryInsertJobOperator`

Comment: Ok I understand, I hope my answer helped you a bit.